# Scala command line parser using Scallop

Tags: scala

I'm fairly new to Scala and need to build a really simple command line parser which provides something like the following which I created using JRuby in a few minutes:-

```
java -jar demo.jar --help

Command Line Example Application

Example: java -jar demo.jar --dn "CN=Test" --nde-url "http://www.example.com" --password "password"

For usage see below:

    -n http://www.example.com
    -p, --password             set the password
    -c, --capi                 set add to Windows key-store
    -h, --help                 Show this message
    -v, --version              Print version
```

[Scallop](https://github.com/Rogach/scallop) looks like it will do the trick, but I can't seem to find a simple example that works! All of the examples I've found seem to be fragmented and don't work for some reason or other.

**UPDATE**

I found this example which works, but I'm not sure how to bind it into the actual args within the main method.

```
import org.rogach.scallop._; 

object cmdlinetest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) 

    val opts = Scallop(List("-d","--num-limbs","1"))
      .version("test 1.2.3 (c) 2012 Mr Placeholder")
      .banner("""Usage: test [OPTION]... [pet-name]
                |test is an awesome program, which does something funny
                |Options:
                |""".stripMargin)
      .footer("\nFor all other tricks, consult the documentation!")
      .opt[Boolean]("donkey", descr = "use donkey mode")
      .opt("monkeys", default = Some(2), short = 'm')
      .opt[Int]("num-limbs", 'k',
      "number of libms", required = true)
      .opt[List[Double]]("params")
      .opt[String]("debug", hidden = true)
      .props[String]('D',"some key-value pairs")
      // you can add parameters a bit later
      .args(List("-Dalpha=1","-D","betta=2","gamma=3", "Pigeon"))
      .trailArg[String]("pet name")
      .verify

    println(opts.help)
  }
}
```

Comment: As for your comment: >"I'm not sure how to bind it into the actual args within the main method", just replace `List("-d","--num-limbs","1")` with `args`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I'll try to add more examples :)

In this case, it would be much better to use ScallopConf:

```
import org.rogach.scallop._

object Main extends App {
  val opts = new ScallopConf(args) {
    banner("""
NDE/SCEP Certificate enrollment prototype

Example: java -jar demo.jar --dn CN=Test --nde-url http://www.example.com --password password

For usage see below:
    """)

    val ndeUrl = opt[String]("nde-url")
    val password = opt[String]("password", descr = "set the password")
    val capi = toggle("capi", prefix = "no-", descrYes = "enable adding to Windows key-store", descrNo = "disable adding to Windows key-store")
    val version = opt[Boolean]("version", noshort = true, descr = "Print version")
    val help = opt[Boolean]("help", noshort = true, descr = "Show this message")

  }

  println(opts.password())
}
```

It prints:

```
$ java -jar demo.jar --help

NDE/SCEP Certificate enrollment prototype

Example: java -jar demo.jar --dn CN=Test --nde-url http://www.example.com --password password

For usage see below:

  -c, --capi              enable adding to Windows key-store 
      --no-capi           disable adding to Windows key-store 
      --help              Show this message 
  -n, --nde-url  <arg>     
  -p, --password  <arg>   set the password 
      --version           Print version
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you read [the documentation](http://rogach.github.com/scallop/#org.rogach.scallop.Scallop)? It looks like all you have to do is call `get` for each option you want:

```
def get [A] (name: String)(implicit m: Manifest[A]): Option[A]
```

It looks like you might need to provide the expected return type in the method call. Try something like this:

```
val donkey = opts.get[Boolean]("donkey")
val numLimbs = opts.get[Int]("num-limbs")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a quick and dirty way to parse command line arguments, you can use [pirate](https://github.com/mosesn/pirate), an extremely barebones way to parse arguments.  Here is what it would look like to handle the usage you describe above:

```
import com.mosesn.pirate.Pirate

object Main {
  def main(commandLineArgs: Array[String]) {
    val args = Pirate("[ -n string ] [ -p string ] [ -chv ]")("-n whatever -c".split(" "))
    val c = args.flags.contains('c')
    val v = args.flags.contains('v')
    val h = args.flags.contains('h')
    val n = args.strings.get("n")
    val p = args.strings.get("p")

    println(Seq(c, v, h, n, p))
  }
}
```

Of course, for your program, you would pass `commandLineArgs` instead of `"-n whatever -c"`.

Unfortunately, pirate does not yet support GNU style arguments, nor the version or help text options.